# What happened to all the Higgledies in Ding Dong Dell?

Tags: ni-no-kuni-2-revenant-kingdom

While running through Ding Dong Dell during chapter 8, I noticed many Higgledies scattered all around the city, mostly in places I couldn't reach. For example: <sub><sup>(Taken from some online tutorial, not my own)</sup></sub>

> [image]

However, at some point in chapter 9 while in Ding Dong Dell again, I realized **all of the Higgledies are gone**! Not a single Higgledy remains in the whole big city. Took screenshot in the same place as the above screenshot, and as you see, nothing where those two cuties were dancing:

> [image]

What happened to all the Higgledies in Ding Dong Dell between chapters 8 and 9? Is it explained somewhere? If some weird glitch, any patch to fix it?

Note it's specific to Ding Dong Dell, not world-wide. Checked Auntie Martha's Cottage and they're all still there, for example.

Still the same even after end game.

Comment: Weird! Is this end game, right before the final boss that you're referring to?

Comment: These look like two totally different graphic settings - which could account for the lack of extra sprites on the screen or them being hidden from site due to increased vegetation

Comment: @ChaseIngebritson chapter 9, I still did not finish the game. Tried in several different points of the main quest, no change.

Comment: @FoxMcCloud no, the second is simply a literal screenshot of my TV since I can't upload actual screenshots from my PS. It has HD resolution. There were Higgledies on my own screen too, I just have no save point in chapter 8 so I looked for something online to make sure I am not getting crazy. :)